# Google maps not loading on specific device in wifi, but working in 3g network

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2, handshake

I used google map v2 with fragment, google maps load fine, but in some device like MiUi and huawei its not loading map in wifi connections and showing unknown Handhshake error, Following is code snippet.

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        setupLocationClient();
        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have wifi permissions? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: Yes, i added all required permission.